# Flux.mergeOrdered() do not order the Flux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a problem with **Flux.mergeOrdered()** method. I have a class **Person**:

```
static class Person {
        int age;
        String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

  //getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return age == person.age && Objects.equals(name, person.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(age, name);
    }
//toString()
    }
```

Now I try to create some Persons, put them in different Fluxes, create comparator and with **Flux.mergeOrdered()** method get one ordered FLux:

```
    Person alex = new Person(13,"Alex");
    Person misha = new Person(12,"Misha");
    Person oleg = new Person(14,"Oleg");
    Person nikita = new Person(66,"Nikita");
    Person dima = new Person(60,"Dima");
    Person kolya = new Person(68,"Kolya");

    Flux<Person> young = Flux.just(alex, misha, oleg);
    Flux<Person> old = Flux.just(nikita, dima, kolya);
    Comparator<Person> personComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge);

    Flux.mergeOrdered(personComparator, young, old).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

My output:

> Person{age=13, name='Alex'}  Person{age=12, name='Misha'}
> Person{age=14, name='Oleg'}  Person{age=66, name='Nikita'}
> Person{age=60, name='Dima'}  Person{age=68, name='Kolya'}

Why the result Flux is not Ordered?

Comment: The [example in the document](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#mergeOrdered-int-java.util.Comparator-org.reactivestreams.Publisher...-) already explain how `mergeOrdered` work

Comment: @samabcde so it takes first element from each flux, and less of them write firstly?

Comment: Yes, this is what I think after reading the document.

Comment: @samabcde do you mind, when it will be useful?

Comment: I think it is useful when you want to merge multiple ordered flux into one ordered flux